# Apply and apply with COQ

Tags: coq

Sorry for the ambiguous question but I'm having hard time understanding the difference between `apply` and `apply with`.

Suppose I have a goal, when should I use `apply` and when should I use `apply with`?
my goal is of the form:
P a b.
And the lemma I'm trying to apply to has forall a b.
If I'm using apply, it just makes the a b constants.
If I'm using apply with it generalizes the a and b.

Comment: Could you perhaps provide a specific example? FWIW, here is the [documentation for 
`apply` (including `apply ... with ...`)](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html?highlight=apply#coq:tacn.apply).

Answer (score 0):

When you look at a theorem statement, you can check whether the universally quantified variables appear in the final conclusion of the statement.  I all of them do appear, you can use `apply`.  If one of them does not, then it is often more practical to use `apply ... with ...`.

Here are two examples.

```
Require Import Arith.
Check le_trans.
(* This says : 
  Nat.le_trans
   : forall n m p : nat, n <= m -> m <= p -> n <= p. *)
Check le_S.
(* This says :
 le_S
  : forall n m : nat, n <= m -> n <= S m *)
Check le_n.
(* This says :
 le_n
  : forall n: nat, n <= n *)m -> n <= S m
```

I am taking examples from the already existing `Arith` library.  The two Check commands make it possible to verify that we are on the same page.  The first one, about `le_trans` shows that in this theorem there is one variable, named `y` in my example, which does not appear in the final statement.  So, when performing an `apply` command, this `y` will not be guessable by comparison with the goal  at hand.  For this reason, this theorem is a good candidate for `apply ... with ...`.

Here is an example proof:

```
Lemma test_drive : forall x, x <= S (S x).
Proof.
intros x.
apply le_trans with (S x).
apply le_S.
apply le_n.
apply le_S.
apply le_n.
end.
```

When applying the theorem `le_trans`, the Coq system can guess which value will be used for instanciating variables named `n` and `p`, by simply comparing with the goal at the time: `n` should should be `x` and `p` should be `S (S x)`.  For `m`, a value should be given, and `apply` expects the user to give it, this is where we use the `with` clause.  In this case, we can simply give the value (the order in which variables appear is being used).  We choose to give `S x`.  As a result, we obtain two goals, one with statement `x <= S x`  and one with statement `S x <= S (S x)`.  Both goals are instances of the final statement of `le_S`.  In turn, this lemma has the property that both universally quantified variables appear in the final statement, so `apply` without the `with` clause can be used.

The same happens later when we want to use the lemma `le_n`.